# Screen density on GS3

Tags: android, android-screen, android-screen-support

I don't understand following point:

- Samsung Galaxy S3 displays 720px x 1280px for a 4.8" screen size
- So the screen density can be evaluated to 305dpi
- In [Android screen-support recommandation page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), 305dpi corresponding to "xhdpi" qualifier

So my question is: **why an app running on GS3 take resources from "mdpi" qualifier ?**

---

As an update, see my code to test it:

**main.xml** :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/density" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**strings.xml** in folders {"**values**","**values-ldpi**","**values-mdpi**","**values-hdpi**","**values-xhdpi**"}

where "**[x]**" is respectively {"**default**","**ldpi**","**mdpi**","**hdpi**","**xhdpi**"} :

```
<resources>

    <string name="density">[x]</string>

</resources>
```

the result is the app show "**mdpi**" text resource

---

As a new update, I tested to :

- rename "**values-xhdpi**" folder to "**values-normal-xhdpi**"

Result : "**xhdpi**"

- rename "**values-xhdpi**" folder to "**values-normal-xhdpi**"
- rename "**values-hdpi**" folder to "**values-normal-hdpi**"

Result : "**hdpi**"

- rename "**values-xhdpi**" folder to "**values-normal-xhdpi**"
- rename "**values-hdpi**" folder to "**values-normal-hdpi**"
- rename "**values-mdpi**" folder to "**values-normal-mdpi**"

Result : "**mdpi**"

- rename "**values-xhdpi**" folder to "**values-normal-xhdpi**"
- rename "**values-hdpi**" folder to "**values-normal-hdpi**"
- rename "**values-mdpi**" folder to "**values-normal-mdpi**"
- rename "**values-ldpi**" folder to "**values-normal-ldpi**"

Result : "**mdpi**"

I don't understand results, why the system selects resources the less selective (with "mdpi" minimum) instead of more selective?

Comment: I think you did something wrong with your test

Comment: Do you have the xhdpi folder? Is it named correctly? Do you have a default resources folder?

Comment: I test my app with a TextView and folders "values-ldpi", "values-mdpi", "values-hdpi", "values-xhdpi" containing respectively "ldpi", "mdpi", "hdpi", "xhdpi" resources text (nothing in "values" folder) and the app show me "mdpi" density

Comment: In addition, I added a ImageView linked to an image reference with resources in differents density sub-folder (adapted to differents screen density) but the image is in poor quality (with an ImageView size equals to image size in "mdpi")

Comment: I tested to put "default" density text value in "values" folder but the application shows me "mdpi". So the resource contained in "values-mdpi" is used...

Comment: Is it possible that "values" don't support alternative resources base on density? (According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources it should, but personally I never had success with values-density pairs myself)

Comment: I have the same effect with image: when I rename "drawable-xhdpi" folder to "drawable-normal-xhdpi", my image is perfect. I don't understand how this hierarchy works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error:

I compile under API level 3, and in my Manifest I deleted property android:targetSdkVersion because it is not recognized (error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'targetSdkVersion' in package 'android'). In the [Range of screens supported](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range) section, we can see that is supported from Android 1.6 (API Level 4).

Thank you for help